# Python regex gotcha

Tags: python, regex

Could you explain me why the first regex doesn't match?

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'\d','.0')
>>> re.match(r'.\d','.0')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x109adbd30>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`re.match()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) tries to match from the beginning of the string.

Use [`re.search()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) instead if you want to locate a match anywhere in the string.

PS: You might want to escape the `.`, because it's a metacharacter that matches any<sup>1</sup> character (so `x0` would match your second example).

```
>>> re.match(r'\.\d', 'x0')
>>> re.match(r'.\d', 'x0')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01F67138>
```

<sup>1</sup> except newlines, unless [`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.S) is used.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're using `match` and that matches a string from beginning (like if you used `^`)

Try `re.search`

Answer (score 1):

For reference to search vs match: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match